# Recuperar cpf com mascara do banco de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um registro de cpf no banco onde está salvo sem a mascara, ao exibir na tela para o usuário eu preciso que o numero seja formato para o tipo cpf, como fazer?

Consegui colocar a mascara quando o usuario vai digitando usando jquery mask assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $Cpf = $("#Cpf");
    $Cpf.mask('000.000.000-00', { reverse: true });
});
```

porem preciso que seja colocado tb no momento de exibição dos dados para o usuário.

Answer (score -1):

siga como ta na documentação:
coloque isso no seu 'head'

```
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js'></script>
```

no seu input vai ficar assim:

```
<input id="cpf" name="cpf" type="text" class="cpf" value="{variavel cpf}">
```

e no final coloca isso

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
    $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
    $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
    $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
    $('.phone').mask('(91) 00000-0000');
    $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
    $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
    $('.mixed').mask('AAA 000-S0S');
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
    $('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
    $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
    $('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
    $('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', {
        translation: {
        'Z': {
            pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
        }
        }
    });
    $('.ip_address').mask('099.099.099.099');
    $('.percent').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});
    $('.clear-if-not-match').mask("00/00/0000", {clearIfNotMatch: true});
    $('.placeholder').mask("00/00/0000", {placeholder: "__/__/____"});
    $('.fallback').mask("00r00r0000", {
        translation: {
            'r': {
            pattern: /[\/]/,
            fallback: '/'
            },
            placeholder: "__/__/____"
        }
        });
    $('.selectonfocus').mask("00/00/0000", {selectOnFocus: true});
    });

</script>
```

ou tente isso:

```
 $string = "33322255588";
    $string1 = substr("$string", 0, 3);
    $string2 = substr("$string", 3, 3);
    $string3 = substr("$string", 6, 3);
    $string4 = substr("$string", 9, 10);
    echo $string1.'.'.$string2.'.'.$string3.'-'.$string4;
```

pra salvar no banco vc tem q tirar a formatação então vc pode fazer isso:

```
    $string = "333.222.555-88";
    $result = explode('.', $string );
    $result2 = explode('-', $result[2] );
    $result3 = $result[0].$result[1].$result2[0].$result2[1];
    echo $result3;
```

Comment: Nao funcionou, a mascara ainda nao é aplicada, está vindo do banco sem mascara e assim permanece

Comment: ta vamos la vc ta exibindo isso dentro de um input ?

Comment: isso assim: `<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control" id="Cpf" name="Cpf" placeholder="Ex.: 010.011.111-00" maxlength="14">`

Comment: quando vc digita  dentro desse input ele formata?

Comment: sim, só nao funciona quando vem do banco...

Comment: ta vamos la então converta os valores, vc ta usando php no back?

Comment: eu editei a minha resposta, olha la no final da minha resposta tem uma coisa que eu fiz em php, n sei qual linguagem no back q vc ta usando, mas basicamente eu formatei a string usando php pegando cada possição e colocando '-' e '.' pois o valor de numero de string do cpf nunca muda, desta forma essa é uma solução, só lembra q vc tem tratar esse valor quando for salvar novamente no banco

Comment: to usando c#, nao quria ter que passar na mao mas acho que vai ser o jeito mesmo

Comment: sim vc vai ter q tratar ela p exibir p usuário(03/02/1992) e tratar quando for inserir no banco(1992-02-03)... nesses formatos